# Granting Access to a User from a Remote Machine - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database in mysql and I would like to grant access to a user from a remote machine. How can this be achieved?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually first thing you need to do is comment `bind-address` in MySql config file (my.cnf). This settings is blocking communication with database if it's not from the the same address, and restart mysql to apply changes. Also don't forget to open port 3306 on which MySql communicate.

Next you can freely create a new database user, which login will be `@'%'`.

**But beware**, if it's a production server, it is not good practice to do this, it is security hole which can be used.

Comment: But I dont know the user that will be accessing, and you cant use wildcard for user right?

Comment: Well, it's your database, so you must define the username which will be accessing.

Comment: Does this refer to the mysql user? Because I have a web application which lets users login and register; The JDBC connection user is my user. So I would use my user?

Comment: The login for your application and the database is not the same thing. The login to your database is the one, your application is using. Not the one, from the application register form.